# Angular4 : Passing input value to service

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4.
I have a variable "md_id" which is binded to the view as follows.

HTML:

```
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of driverData">
                        <td class="align-right" id="md_id" [(ngModel)]="item.md_id" name="driverId" ngDefaultControl (click)="runPromo()">{{item.driver_name}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

JSON:

```
[{"md_id": 1, "driver_name": "A"}, {"md_id": 2, "driver_name": "B"}, {"md_id": 3, "driver_name": "C"}, {"md_id": 4, "driver_name": "D"}]
```

I want that based on the value of md_id selected, it should pass that particular value of md_id to another service that can display the results accordingly based upon the selection.

The selected value of md_id should be passed to the following service.

Service:

```
public getName(md_id){
   return this.http.get(url+'/api/names?md_id='+md_id)
   .map((resService: Response) => resService.json())
    }
```

Component:

```
 this.calendarService.getName(this.md_id).subscribe(data => this.promoName = data);
```

Could you please help me in knowing how can I pass the value of one service binded in the view to be passed into another service.

Am I missing here something?

Please help.

Comment: are you trying something like this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxj78j?file=app/app.component.html, click on each cell and check console for selected cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**HTML:**

Pass '**item**' as parameter of runPromo()

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of driverData">
                        <td class="align-right" id="md_id" [(ngModel)]="item.md_id" name="driverId" ngDefaultControl (click)="runPromo(item)">{{item.driver_name}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

**Component:**

Add service to the providers of Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [CalendarService]
})
```

assign md_id to service - CalendarService in component service call

```
  constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService) {

    this.runPromo = (v) =>{ 
       this.calendarService.getName(v.md_id).subscribe(data => this.promoName = data);
    this.promo1= !this.promo1;    
   }
  }
```

code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-ukuoyd?file=app/app.service.ts

Comment: It is giving the below response in the console: XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=[object%20Object]"

Comment: this.calendarService.getName(v.md_id).subscribe(data => this.promoName = data);  will change object for md_id to md_id value

Comment: after that localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=1 should work in browser if service is working

Comment: In that case , should not it be displaying the following message in the console:: GET "localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=1"; instead of : XHR failed loading: GET "localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=[object%20Object]";

Comment: 'v'  is the item value - {md_id :1 , driver_name:'A'} object , so in the calendar service , use v.md_id  to form the correct url as localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=1

Comment: I have also added v.md_id in the calendar service ,but it is picking "localhost:8000/api/promotionnames?md_id=[object%20Object]". However in component, it is displaying the correct md_id in the console log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168074/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-neha-uniyal).

Comment: add console to check the md_id parameter in the public getName(md_id){ console.log(md_id);
   return this.http.get(url+'/api/names?md_id='+md_id)
   .map((resService: Response) => resService.json())
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused about the `md_id` and `driverData.md_id`.

You're not setting the `md_id` variable anywhere, only the `driverData.md_id`.

The best way to accomplish what you're trying to do, is:

```
<td class="align-right" id="md_id" [(ngModel)]="item.md_id" name="driverId" ngDefaultControl (click)="runPromo(item)">{{item.driver_name}}
```

And then:

```
function promo(item) {
    this.calendarService.getName(item.md_id).subscribe(data => this.promoName = data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the variable to the `click` method like this:
`(click)="runPromo(item.md_id)"`

And call the service in the method body of `runPromo`

Fundamentals: https://angular.io/guide/user-input